# Export ARM_CLIENT_ID and ARM_CLIENT_SECRET from Service connection in pipeline.yaml

Tags: azure-devops

I have created pipeline to import existing Azure Resource into terraform. Since Terraform Import requires Provider details or Environment Variables for The below details which has to extracted from the Service Connection.

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Terraform Init
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.service_connection }} 
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
        export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
        export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
        export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id | xargs)
        export ARM_TENANT_ID=$(az account show --query tenantId | xargs)
        ls
        terraform init -upgrade -input=false  \
            -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ parameters.tf_state_subscription_id }}" \
            -backend-config="tenant_id=$tenantId" \
            -backend-config="client_id=$servicePrincipalId" \
            -backend-config="client_secret=$servicePrincipalKey" \
            -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ parameters.resource_group_name }}" \
            -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ parameters.storage_account_name }}" \
            -backend-config="container_name=${{ parameters.tf_state_key }}" \
            -backend-config="key=${{ parameters.tf_state_key }}.tfstate"
        if [ $(az resource list --name pytestkeyvault --query '[].id' -o tsv) != null ]
        then
          echo "using Keyvault $(az resource list --name pytestkeyvault --query '[].id' -o tsv)"
          terraform import azurerm_key_vault.this $(az resource list --name pytestkeyvault --query '[].id' -o tsv) 
        else
          echo "Keyvault does not exist"
        fi
echo $ARM_CLIENT_ID
```

The exported environment variable ARM_CLIENT_ID is empty. The below variables are not being exported as environment variables.

echo $ARM_CLIENT_ID
echo $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
echo $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
echo $ARM_TENANT_ID

Comment: You can try to use `$env:servicePrincipalId` instead.  You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/836430/no-values-available-for-service-principal-variable.html) with similar issue .

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin OP is in LInux environment... Read the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using system variables $env:servicePrincipalId, $env:servicePrincipalKey, $env:tenantId to get SPN details.

Answer (score 0):

For my setup i could not access the service principal from azure powershell.
But i could from Azure CLI.

This post pointed me in the right direction, check it out:
https://www.integration-playbook.io/docs/combining-az-cli-and-azure-powershell-az-modules-in-a-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

In my experience of trying every possible variation of setting environment variables, it seems as ADO build agents don't allow the persisting of `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET` as an environment variable.

So the workaround I had to do was set the environment variables at the task level (instead of at the shell/machine level):

```
- script: |
  terraform init # ...rest of your CLI arguments/backend-config flags
env:
  ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(client_secret)
displayName: Terraform Init
```

Edit:
IMO, just using `terraform init` yourself via CLI is better than using the `AzureCLI@2` task which is a confusing black box that honestly makes it harder/more verbose to do the same thing just with the plan CLI command.